# In route53 weighted routing how can I use or pass arguments in ResourceRecords value field using python/boto3?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I am using aws lambda.

```
"Action": "UPSERT",
                "ResourceRecordSet": {
                    "Name": "hello.example.com.",
                    "Type": "CNAME",
                    "TTL": 60,
                    "Weight": 0,
                    "SetIdentifier": "green",
                    "ResourceRecords": [{ "Value": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/v1" }]
                    }
```

In ResourceRecords, normally I use string but want to use arguments but how?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clarify what you are asking? Is it how to substitute a variable into the JSON? Can't you just use it, eg `"ResourceRecords": [{"Value": my_variable}]`?

Comment: "ResourceRecords": [{"Value": arguments}]

--- I want to use this actually.

Comment: Are you having a particular problem? If so, please edit the question to show your code.

Comment: No, it's not a problem. Actually I want know is it possible to use arguments as a ResourceRecords or not? If possible then how?

Comment: I'm confused. The code in the above comment shows how you can use variables in objects. Can you possibly edit your question to clarify what you are asking, with an example?

Comment: Clear your confusion, above code is ok and execute successfully. 
"ResourceRecords": [{"Value": my_variable}]  --- is ok.
"ResourceRecords": [{"Value": arguments}]  --- is it possible? if possible then how?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Need a example using arguments as "ResourceRecords" value.

Comment: There are examples on: [Route 53 Template Snippets - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-route53.html)